# How to select multiple values in one column many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

[Table description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGmC8.png)

```
CREATE TABLE `attribute` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255)    DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255)    DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255)    DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `product_attribute` (
  `product_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `attribute_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  KEY `FKefc9famxhv98xs6686269a79` (`attribute_id`),
  KEY `FKlefs59y5kmsbu017n1wp10gf2` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKefc9famxhv98xs6686269a79` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `attribute` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKlefs59y5kmsbu017n1wp10gf2` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO `product`VALUES (1,'LAPTOP A'),(2,'LAPTOP B')
INSERT INTO `attribute` VALUES  (1,'branch','Acer'),(2,'branch','Dell'),
                (3,'screen','13 Inch'),(4,'screen','15.6 Inch')     
INSERT INTO `product_attribute` VALUES (1,1),(1,3),(2,2),(2,4)
```

Example1:
I want to select products with **attribute name=branch** and **attribute value=Acer** and **attribute name=screen** and **attribute value = 13 Inch**

Example2:
I want to select products with **attribute name=branch** and (**attribute value=Acer** or **attribute value=Dell**) and **attribute name=screen** and (**attribute value = 13 Inch** or **attribute value = 15.6 Inch**)

possible 3 or more attributes may be required...
I tried everything but all failed.

Comment: Instead of screen images, add code to your question for the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for sample data. Also, add the query you've tried, even if not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example - 1 (query) -

```
select p.* from product p
where p.id in (
select distinct pa.product_id 
from attribute a join product_attribute pa
on 
pa.attribute_id = a.id
and (a.name,a.value) in (('branch','Acer'),('screen','13 Inch'))
)
```

Example - 1 (Query) - similar to above, slightly different approach

```
select distinct p.*
from product p join product_attribute pa
on p.id = pa.product_id 
join attribute a
on a.id = pa.attribute_id
and (a.name,a.value) in (('branch','Acer'),('screen','13 Inch'))
```

Example -2 (query) -

```
select distinct p.*
from product p join product_attribute pa
on p.id = pa.product_id 
join attribute a
on a.id = pa.attribute_id
and (a.name,a.value) in (('branch','Acer'),('branch','Dell'), ('screen','13 Inch'),('screen','15.6 Inch'))
```

Modified query to select products with both attributes -

```
select distinct p.*
from product p join product_attribute pa1
on p.id = pa1.product_id 
join product_attribute pa2
on pa1.product_id = pa2.product_id
and 
pa1.attribute_id in 
(select a.id from attribute a where (a.name,a.value) in (('branch','acer'),('branch','Dell')))
and pa2.attribute_id in 
(select a.id from attribute a where (a.name,a.value) in (('screen','13 Inch'),('screen','15.6 Inch')))
```

You can refer to the db fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ihygssmwErvhb4ekcUnG5/5)

Required: Matching attrbutes should be atleast given in query or more.

```
select distinct p.*
from product p 
where p.id in 
(
select pa1.product_id from 
product_attribute pa1,
product_attribute pa2,
product_attribute pa3
where 
pa1.attribute_id in 
(select a.id from attribute a where (a.name,a.value) in (('branch','acer'),('branch','Dell')))
and pa2.attribute_id in
(select a.id from attribute a where (a.name,a.value) in (('screen','13 Inch'),('screen','15.6 Inch')))
and pa3.attribute_id in
(select a.id from attribute a where (a.name,a.value) in (('need','gaming')))
and pa1.product_id = pa2.product_id
and pa2.product_id = pa3.product_id
and pa1.product_id = pa3.product_id
)
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ihygssmwErvhb4ekcUnG5/3) for above query

[Two](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ihygssmwErvhb4ekcUnG5/4) - Matching attributes:

[Four](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ihygssmwErvhb4ekcUnG5/5) - Matching attributes:

Comment: It would be wrong if add Laptop C :
INSERT INTO `product`VALUES (1,'LAPTOP A'),(2,'LAPTOP B'),(3,'LAPTOP C');
INSERT INTO `attribute` VALUES  (1,'branch','Acer'),(2,'branch','Dell'),
                (3,'screen','13 Inch'),(4,'screen','15.6 Inch'),(5,'branch','Asus');
INSERT INTO `product_attribute` VALUES (1,1),(1,3),(2,2),(2,4),(3,5),(3,4); 
See at:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5490f06c21a10c181bcb841ba80db263

Comment: it must have both `name='branch'` and `name='screen'`

Comment: I have added the modified query in response.

Comment: It will fail if product belongs to 3 or more attributes Example: `name='branch' and name='screen' and name ='need'` See at: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4aaf9efa1748bff8b08057e49dcbb5a5

Comment: Included new query in response, please refer same.